# Initial Value Problem = Interval of Validity when P(t) = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Here is an initial value problem =

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} = \sec^2t
$$

subject to the condition that $y(30) = \tan(30)$.

**Question = Write $y$ as a function of $t$. Also, on what interval is the solution valid?**

My attempt =

So $y$ is quite simply equal to $\tan t$. The real issue is the interval of validity. The general solution to this type of problem is to write the equation as $y'(t) + p(t) y = g(t)$ subject to the condition $y(t_n) = y_n$,

So in this case we know that $t_n = 30$ and $p(t)$ seems to be zero. We know $t_n$ must be contained inside the interval. The second thing we know is that all values for which $p(t)$ and $g(t)$ are discontinuous must be excluded form the interval. So basically all we need is an interval that (i) contains 30 and (ii) ensures that $\sec^2t$ is continuous. Thus my solution is that $26.84 < t < 30.0022$

But this answer is wrong. Can someone kindly explain? Thank you.

Comment: Your answer should involve $\pi $, not decimals. Also, the interval should be of length $\pi $.

Comment: So my interval is coming out to be 8.55pi < t < 9.55pi. But its still wrong. At t = 30, the function almost discontinuous, so i imagine the interval barely includes 30. If you look at the graph of (sec(t)^2). as t gets closer to 30, the function gets closer to infinity. So what to do now?

Comment: Why 8.55? It should be 8.5 and 9.5. Cosine vanishes at half-integer multiples of pi.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the entire issue is based on radians/degrees.  Take $tan(30)=tan(\pi/6) = \sqrt{3}/3$

Unless I'm mistaken, $Sec^2(t)$ has vertical asymptotes at $t=\frac {n\pi}2$ where $n$ is any integer, thus your interval would be $[\frac{-\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2]$.

Comment: In degrees $\frac{d}{dt} \tan(t) = \sec^2(t)$ is not true, so in fact I suspect that this problem is formulated in radians (it is just referencing the slightly "weird" value of 30 radians).